# Plot mean and 95% CI values using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
        Region    Year   Crop          Yield     Lower CI     Upper CI
0    Argentina  2017.0   Soya    2770.885366  2647.711922  2937.259244
1    Argentina  2018.0   Soya    3442.598073  3375.280283  3512.806645
2    Argentina  2019.0   Soya    3472.638859  3415.621142  3536.144550
3    Argentina  2020.0   Maize   6203.009997  6020.164203  6387.457295
```

Using the dataframe above, I want to plot each row using the data in the Yield, Lower CI and Upper CI columns. The Yield value should be represented as a dot and the Lower and Upper CI values should be represented like a box plot, sort of like:

[image]

Each Crop should be represented using a different color, while each year should be a different shade of the same color for that crop. Is there a way to do this using either seaborn or matplotlib?

Comment: What do you want to be shown on the x-axis?

Comment: I want to show Crop and Year on X-axis. Basically, each row of data frame will be a separate box plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer using `matplotlib` that will get you started, then you can tell me what else you need. Note that with the data you've given us, the plot isn't so interesting, since none of the crops have overlapping years. So far the different shades per year isn't included (is it really needed?).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

# Get the lower and upper "error bars"
df = df.assign(Lower=df["Yield"] - df["Lower CI"], Upper=df["Upper CI"] - df["Yield"])

# Make a new figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Group the data by crop, and iterate through each crop
for crop, data in df.groupby("Crop"):
    ax.errorbar(
        data["Year"],
        data["Yield"],
        yerr=(data["Lower"], data["Upper"]),
        fmt="o",
        label=crop,
        capsize=5,
    )
ax.legend()
# This sets the x-axis to have ticks on years (so we don't get e.g. 2019.5)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator())
ax.set(xlabel="Year", ylabel="Yield")
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot it produces
[image]